# not malicious hidden link

Tags: jquery, seo, search-engine, fancybox

hey i'm using a jquery plugin [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net), which is a Lightbox type plugin.
This plugin can only be triggered by clicking a link. I want to show the plugin on PostBack.
 I have no problem doing this programmatically.
My concerns are purely from an SEO perspective. How can I add a hidden link that wouldn't be identified as trying to cheat Google and other search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is don't. Just add the no follow tag to the link e.g.

```
<a href="mylink" rel="nofollow">my link</a>
```

Goggle now wont follow it / it wont effect your SEO, also I would add the location to the robots .txt and make sure its not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a sure fire way to do this (otherwise it would be exploited and then become bad practise again). Having said that it appears to be quite rare that this happens. I use hidden elements fairly frequently to ensure accessibility and I've not had a problem before.

Check out [this post and comments](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201010/is_hiding_text_with_css_to_improve_accessibility_bad_for_seo/) for some additional thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iframes. What's inside an iframe isn't indexed by engines. (at the movement) I know this is a step backwards in technology. It also isn't visible to screen readers. (not very accessible) There is extensive documentation showing that Google still indexes pages even if the link there says "nofollow"